# Wudu without washing face

Tags: wudu

Salaam,

I have bad eczema on my face and as a result i have to daily put on moisturizers and creams that are quite oily. Water spoils these creams and therefore washing my face results in my skin not recieving the benefits of these creams.

Is it possible to do wudu without washing ones face due to these circumstances?

Jazakallah

Comment: We are not a fatwa site.......

Comment: Then what are you? I've asked a question and would like you to answer it.